# ¿Como concatenar correctamente?

Tags: javascript, web

He estado aprendiendo Javascript por mi cuenta, con la ayuda de Videos, Libros, Tutoriales y de mas informacion que he encontrado por internet; me he fijado que en varios lugares usan **+** y **,** para concatenar elementos, asi que me surgio la duda de saber ¿Cual es la manera correcta de concatenar en JS? ¿Que diferencia hay entre usar **,**(coma) y **+**(mas)? ¿Es lo mismo? ¿En que ocaciones deberia usar uno o otro?

Adjunto mi ejemplo:

```js
var numero = "numero";
var palabra = 55;

document.write(numero + palabra + "<br/>");
document.write(numero, palabra);
```

Comment: Que yo sepa, no puedes concatenar con `,` en javascript.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces que ocurre en un caso como el siguiente:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VOOPKx

Comment: con las + se concatena, con las comas tiene que ver con que la funcion está recibiendo más de un parametro

Comment: ¿Y en caso de que no este usando una funcion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, hay que hacer algunas aclaraciones para poder comprenderlo de mejor manera:

> write() es una función y recibe uno o varios parámetros, la finalidad de esta función es imprimir los parametros que recibe como una cadena concatenada

tomando en cuenta esto, a dicha función la puedes sobrecargar con muchos parametros, cada parámetro separado por comas, ejemplo:

```
 document.write("a");
 document.write("a", "b", "c");
 document.write("a", "b", "c");
```

Por otro lado, las variables que recibe esta función pueden ser de diferentes tipos: enteros, cadenas, flotantes y hasta booleanos:

```
 document.write("a", 2, true);
```

---

Ahora hablemos de la concatenación de cadenas: Una cadena se concatena por medio del signo `+`(y tambien permite que concatenes diferentes tipos de variables):

```
 var cadena = numero + palabra + "<br/>"
```

Si te fijas, en el ultimo ejemplo toda esa concatenación cuenta como una sola variable, cuando la ponemos en una funcion, la llamamos parámetro.

Entonces, la función `write()` tiene como proposito recibir parámetros y todos esos parametros los imprime concatenados

```
document.write(numero + palabra + "<br/>");
document.write(numero, palabra);
```

En la primera solo recibe un parametro pero este parametro ya está concatenado, en la segunda recibe 2 pero aqui se encarga de concatenarlos la función.

Es probable que esto sea confuso con la funcion write está concatena, pero si tomamos como ejemplo otra función esto sería más claro aún.

Answer (score 2):

La sintaxis para write es la siguiente: 
document.write(exp1, exp2, exp3, ...)

Acepta una o más expresiones.

En realidad solo estás concatenando en la primera opción. Al usar "+" estás concatenando la expresión 1 con la expresión dos, es decir estás concatenando las variables palabras con número, generando una nueva expresión.

En la segunda opción le estás pasando dos expresiones, lo cual es completamente válido según la sintaxis de write, sin embargo, estrictamente no estás concatenando.

La primera opción la puedes usar cuando son valores pequeños o fáciles de visualizar. 
Para casos donde tus variables son bloques enteros de html yo usaria la opción dos.

Answer (score 1):

La mejor manera para concatenar en JS es el (+) debido que la (,) es utilizada en muchos casos como inclusión en parámetro en funciones o en otras implemenaciones del js esto quiere decir que al especificar la coma (,) ciertos elementos son valorados por separados  ***"esto es en ciertos casos"*** mientras que si se incluye el (+) se establece como una sola cadena o concatencion volviendo 2 elementos como un solo valor,

si buscas concatenar recomiendo usar:

```
var cadena1 = "Hola ";
var cadena2 = "Mundo";
cadena1.concat(cadena2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar una `,` dentro de un `console.write` o `console.log` no significa que concatenes, si no que estas imprimiendo dos variables distintas en un solo output.

```js
let myNum  = 10,
    myBool = false,
    myStr  = 'Foo';
    
document.write( myNum, myBool, myStr );
```

Esto no es concatenación, es unicamente una salida de 3 valores son escribir 3 veces `document.write` esto se demuestra así

```js
let myNum  = 10,
    myBool = false,
    myStr  = 'Foo';
    
document.write( typeof myNum, typeof myBool, typeof myStr );
```

Estamos viendo que cada variable tiene un tipo de dato, si estuviera concatenado, sería un string todo.

---

Hay dos sencillas formas de concatenar, con el operador de `+` o con interpolación de variables

```js
let myNum  = 10,
    myBool = false,
    myStr  = 'Foo';

//Concatenar por +
document.write( myNum + myBool + myStr + '<br>' );

//Esto si tiene un tipo de dato
document.write( typeof(myNum + myBool + myStr) + '<hr>' );

//Concatenar por interpolación utilizando backtick **`**
document.write( `${ myNum } ${ myBool } ${ myStr }` )
```

Quiero que veas como se comportan todas las impresiones ya sea al DOM o a consola

La concatenación por operador, si te das cuenta está sumando el número con el booleano, esto lo interpreta Javascript como 10 + 0 (Javascript interviene en la conversión del Bool a entero y false significa 0 / true es 1) y luego está concatenando la cadena, en el momento que concatenas la cadena, todo se vuelve un `String` y por eso la suma de las 3 variables en el en segundo `document.write`
el retorno del tipo de dato es una cadena.

El tercer ejemplo estamos usando `interpolación` de variables con `literal template`  eso supone una mejora al momento de renderizar la información, puesto que con una simple sintaxis puedes convertir todo a cadena y concatenar a tu gusto y forma.

Es cuestión de formas de trabajo, y puedes usar cualquiera dependiendo de lo que quieras lograr

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando **`","`** para concatenar, se genera un espacio entre el texto y la variable, cosa que con `**"+"**` no.
Es el único diferencial.

Comment: var nombre = "Carlos";
console.log("Nombre =",nombre);

Completamente seguro?

Comment: Eso no es concatenar.

Comment: De acuerdo con la RAE( https://dle.rae.es/?id=A6EsxFh ) y Wikipedia( https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenaci%C3%B3n ) eso SI es concatenar; **La concatenación o conduplicación es, en general, el acto de unir o enlazar cosas.**

Comment: El resultado de esa linea de codigo es la concatenacion de los dos parametros, pero en esa linea de codigo no estas concatenando nada, estas pasando dos parametros a la funcion `write` o `log`.  Esas funciones se encargan de hacer la concatenacion. pero tu no estas concatenando nada.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion.